# What is the best way to remove HTML tags in a string using Python?

Tags: python, html, string, replace

I would like to know what would be the most efficient way to clean all of the HTML tags from this string using python.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing 
elit</strong></p>, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</br> 
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 
</br> 
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
<a href="">Excepteur sint occaecat</a> 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

I tried using replace('[insert tag]', '') but I have to create multiple replace() lines to remove all of the tags.

Answer (score 3):

One way to remove HTML tags from a string is using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library. Calling the text() function extracts all the text and strips all tags.

BeautifulSoup will parse and remove only HTML tags and not just remove any sequence of text starting with a '<' and ending with a '>'. It will also auto-translate HTML entities; e.g. `&lt;` => '<', `&gt;` => '>', etc.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing 
elit</strong></p>, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</br> 
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 
</br> 
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
<a href="">Excepteur sint occaecat</a> 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.text)
```

**Output:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import re

def remove_html_tags(text):
    clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
    return re.sub(clean, '', text)
```

There are several ways to remove HTML tags from a string in Python.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

### **REGEX**

The easiest way is to use regex to remove the tags. To do this, you need to first `import re`. Then you want to remove everything inside <>. To do this, you use `remover = re.compile('<.*?>')`

The full code should look something like this:

```py
import re

string = '''<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing 
elit</strong></p>, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</br> 
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 
</br> 
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
<a href="">Excepteur sint occaecat</a> 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>'''


remover = re.compile('<.*?>')
print(re.sub(remover, '', string))
```

### **LXML**

Another way is to use the `lxml` library, which can be installed with `pip install lxml` The lxml module has a built in function to remove all the tags from html.

The code would look something like this:

```py
from lxml import html

string = '''<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing 
elit</strong></p>, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</br> 
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 
</br> 
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
<a href="">Excepteur sint occaecat</a> 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>'''

print(html.fromstring(string).text_content())
```

The code `html.fromstring(string).text_content()` is what converts the html into text, and thus removes all the tags from it.

Comment: How would I remove tags and escape strings like '&rsquo;'?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code above removes tags from your string. Could you perhaps send an example

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single line to remove tags without need for `re` module. For instance using `expr` in Python 2.7. Try this:

```
heading = 'hello<br>\n<br/>there'

' '.join([s for s in [s.split('>')[-1].strip() for s in heading.split('<')] if s])

>>> 'hello there'
```